# Battery saver mode in ubuntu and mint

Tags: power-management, gnome-power-manager

I have gone through sites and instaled various battery saver tools like tlp lui I actually dont remember their exact name. But non of those helped to save my laptop battery.  Windows 8.1 gives me 3 to 3.5 hour battery backup but mint just gives 2 hours. 
Please suggest me some good tools to enable battery saver in linux.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the desktop environment you are using for Ubuntu and Mint will also play a role in how long your battery will last. For example Unity (Default for Ubuntu) will require more resources than LXDE. It's the same story for mint; if you are using KDE expect a higher amount of consumed resources.

I would recommend you try using different Desktop environments.

Comment: There are tools like tlp and laptop mode tool but they don't seem to preserve battery life

Comment: Okay I have gone through articles and found `ubuntu mate` very suitable